# Create a visual calendar in Excel via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

my program does what I expect to do.
I'm not happy with the last loop.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub calendar()
Dim i, j

Dim mDay As Date
For i = 1 To 12
    Cells(1, i + 1).Value = MonthName(i)
    For j = 2 To 32
        If IsDate(j - 1 & "/" & i & "/" & Year(Date)) Then
           mDay = CDate(j - 1 & "/" & i & "/" & Year(Date))
            Cells(j, i + 1).Value = mDay
            If Weekday(mDay) = 1 Then
                Cells(j, i + 1).Interior.Color = vbRed
                ElseIf Weekday(mDay) = 7 Then
                Cells(j, i + 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                Else
                Cells(j, i + 1).ClearFormats
            End If
                      Cells(j, i + 1).Value = Format(mDay, "DDDD")
                    
        End If
    Next j
Next I
For i = 1 To 31
    Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = i
Next i
End Sub
```

I already have a loop that counts to 31 but if I put it in there it would be executed 12 times.
is there a smarter way to do it?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What do you mean by "smarter?"

Comment: Let me rephrase it. 
How would you solve the problem? I automatically assume it'd be _smarter_ . :)
In my guts, it feels wrong to have an additional loop´.

Comment: Your approach looks fine to me.

Comment: Fine that's an answer I can live. 
I can't improve the code. I'm here to learn and improve.
(Appart from dim i,j which **is** terrible)

Comment: `dim i,j` is terrible indeed, I would replace it by `dim index_month, index_day as integer` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will allocate the value into an array then write into the worksheet 1 time, should be faster that way. (Read/Write to/from cells are expensive operation)

Then use conditional formatting for `Sunday` and `Saturday`:

```
Public Sub calendar()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Dim outputArr() As Variant
    ReDim outputArr(1 To 32, 1 To 13) As Variant

    For i = 1 To 12
        outputArr(1, i + 1) = MonthName(i)
        For j = 2 To 32
            If IsDate(j - 1 & "/" & i & "/" & Year(Date)) Then
                outputArr(j, i + 1) = Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), i, j - 1), "DDDD")
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    For i = 1 To 31
        outputArr(i + 1, 1) = i
    Next i
    
    Dim calendarRng As Range
    Set calendarRng = Range("A1").Resize(32, 13)
    
    Dim formatSunday As FormatCondition
    Set formatSunday = calendarRng.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, Formula1:="=" & Chr(34) & Format(Date - Weekday(Date, vbSunday) + 1, "DDDD") & Chr(34))
    formatSunday.Interior.Color = vbRed
    
    Dim formatSaturday As FormatCondition
    Set formatSaturday = calendarRng.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, Formula1:="=" & Chr(34) & Format(Date - Weekday(Date, vbSaturday) + 1, "DDDD") & Chr(34))
    formatSaturday.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    
    calendarRng.Value = outputArr
End Sub
```

Comment: thanx works fine 
Minor issue you swapped the colors of sunday/saturday :)
and 
minor Bug: It only works in US in other languages you have to change the code (""Sunday"") to (""whatever"") but it is easy to change the conditional formating

Comment: @webwohnraum oops sorry about that, I'll edit it for completeness.

Comment: @webwohnraum I thought Sunday is red and Saturday is Yellow? Anyway it's easy for you to make the change. I have changed the `Formula1` argument to take in the `Format` return of Sun/Sat so it should work for other language now too.

Comment: Nah it was my error.  I typed 
formatSunday = ... =""Saturady""") 
:facepalm: I'm sorry about that

Comment: Question though I don't get the 
Date - Weekday(Date, vbSaturday)+1
How does that work? 
isn't date the date of today? 
When I debug.Print Date - Weekday(Date, vbSaturday) + 1I get 14.08.2021

Comment: Ah yes sorry I am editing through the phone so its my mistake. About your question, basically its a way to get a [day] of the week. I only need the date of a Saturday and Sunday so this is the easiest way (to me) to get one and pass it to `Format` function @webwohnraum

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236151/discussion-between-webwohnraum-and-raymond-wu).

Answer (score 0):

try to move the statement inside the inner loop and check for `i = 1` to only let it execute once.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub calendar()
Dim i, j

Dim mDay As Date
For i = 1 To 12
    Cells(1, i + 1).Value = MonthName(i)
    For j = 2 To 32
        If IsDate(j - 1 & "/" & i & "/" & Year(Date)) Then
           mDay = CDate(j - 1 & "/" & i & "/" & Year(Date))
            Cells(j, i + 1).Value = mDay
            If Weekday(mDay) = 1 Then
                Cells(j, i + 1).Interior.Color = vbRed
                ElseIf Weekday(mDay) = 7 Then
                Cells(j, i + 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                Else
                Cells(j, i + 1).ClearFormats
            End If
                      Cells(j, i + 1).Value = Format(mDay, "DDDD")
                    
        End If
        if i = 1 then cells(j ,1).value = j - 1
    Next j
Next I
'For i = 1 To 31
'    Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = i
'Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: No explanation provided.

Comment: added explanation

Comment: How's the time used. 
( it doesn't matter in this case-just out of curiosity) 
If it would be 1 Million lines would the additional if check take longer instead of the Additional loop?

Comment: @webwohnraum:  The best way to find that out is to measure the code's performance with a timer or profiler.

Comment: @webwohnraum: while i think about it - you can put `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual: Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning of the sub and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` at the end, as this changes performance a lot

Comment: thanx I did't knew about .calculation = xlCalculationManual/xlCalculationAutomatic

Comment: @webwohnraum I think 2 individual loops would be faster at 12 columns and 1 million rows, as you will do the `if` 12 million times, rather than 1 million in a separate loop. If you're after speed, nested loops are usually things you want to avoid, instead of 12*31 use rather 1 loop to loop through 365 days)